# Wrong position of superscript with colored brackets

Tags: color, brackets, superscripts

Coloring the brackets changes the position of the superscript. How can I get the same position as in the right example with standard color brackets? I intend to use `\left)` and `\right)` for brackets to get adapted bracket sizes in larger equations than in the given minimal example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
$\color{red}\left(\right)\color{black}^2 \left(\right)^2$
\end{document}
```

Comment: you are adding the superscript to the color node not the bracket use `^{\textcolor{black}{2}}`

Comment: `${\color{red}\left(\right)^{\color{black}2}} \left(\right)^{2}$` does the trick, like @DavidCarlisle said